# 4 Equal Columns in one Row not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3

currently i building a website with typo3 as CMS and for the responsive design i use twitter bootstrap. now i try make 4 equal columns in one row like the example from this site: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/hero.html

there is 3 columns in one row, I'm looking at the source code and they make it with the row tag and then they put a span tag, i follow these and get a different result, like this:

http://i41.tinypic.com/2lu2hy0.png

my code:

```
<div class="container">

      <!-- Main hero unit for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>

      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your markup looks fine. How are you including the `bootstrap.css` file? Any browser console errors?

Comment: in the header i added the following lines: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.1375689518.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" media="all"> i don't think that i have errors, cause, the site would be display. an other "problem" the site is currently working only local

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK. Now i have looking at the bhootstrap side and looking specially the example. I'm very sure that the layout i posted do it with col-lg, but now they do it with span. OK i'm check my bootstrap css and look, the css from yesterday have include the col and the css from a moment have the span. FINAL: i took the solution with the col, i have seen there is another col, the name is "col-3" thats define with 25% and thats perfect for my problem.